# Mean for number of entries with certain ID in R?

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, average, split-apply-combine

So suppose I have a dataset that looks like this that I'm working with in R:

```
player      at_bat  opponent_name     game  result
Torri_Hunter    1   Pittsburgh Pirates  1   home run
Torri_Hunter    2   Pittsburgh Pirates  1   triple
Torri_Hunter    3   Pittsburgh Pirates  1   strikeout
Torri_Hunter    4   Pittsburgh Pirates  1   strikeout
Torri_Hunter    1   Pittsburgh Pirates  2   groundout
Torri_Hunter    2   Pittsburgh Pirates  2   home run
Torri_Hunter    3   Pittsburgh Pirates  2   flyout
Torri_Hunter    1   Pittsburgh Pirates  2   home run
Torri_Hunter    2   Pittsburgh Pirates  3   triple
Torri_Hunter    3   Pittsburgh Pirates  3   strikeout
Torri_Hunter    4   Pittsburgh Pirates  3   strikeout
Torri_Hunter    1   Detroit Tigers      1   home run
Torri_Hunter    2   Detroit Tigers      1   home run
Torri_Hunter    3   Detroit Tigers      1   home run
Torri_Hunter    4   Detroit Tigers      1   strikeout
```

(I realize Torii's name is spelled wrong, bear with me here).

And I ultimately want to calculate the percentage of home runs by game in a series, ending up with something that looks like this:

```
                opponent_name       game_1s game_2s game_3s
Torri Hunter    Pittsburgh Pirates  25%     50%     0%
Torri Hunter    Detroit Tigers      75%     --      --
```

I could dplyr::filter down results, tally() each game's stats by ID, and then export to .csv where I can get the averages in excel (and that's what I've been doing), but there's got to be a quicker way to do this entirely in R.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(player, opponent_name, game) %>% 
  summarise(p = sum(result == "home run") / n())
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: player, opponent_name
#
#        player      opponent_name game    p
#1 Torri_Hunter     Detroit Tigers    1 0.75
#2 Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates    1 0.25
#3 Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates    2 0.50
#4 Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates    3 0.00
```

To match your desired output you could also do:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(player, opponent_name, game) %>% 
  summarise(p = mean(result == "home run")) %>%
  tidyr::spread(game, p) %>%
  arrange(desc(opponent_name)) %>%
  setNames(c(names(.)[1:2], paste0("game_", names(.)[3:5], "s"))) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), "--", paste0(. * 100, "%"))), -(player:opponent_name))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
#
#        player      opponent_name game_1s game_2s game_3s
#1 Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates     25%     50%      0%
#2 Torri_Hunter     Detroit Tigers     75%      --      --
```

Comment: Why not use `mean` instead of sum(...)/n()

Comment: Just a question though, Steven.  This works perfectly, I'm just wondering how the summarize function knows that the n() you're using is the local value of n, by ID, and not the n for the entire column?  Thanks again!

Comment: `n()` is actually the group size of `player, opponent_name, game`

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution with casting would be

```
require(data.table)
setDT(dat)
percentage <- dat[,mean(result == "home run"), by = c("player", "opponent_name", "game")]
```

Result:

```
> percentage

         player      opponent_name game   V1
1: Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates    1 0.25
2: Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates    2 0.50
3: Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates    3 0.00
4: Torri_Hunter     Detroit Tigers    1 0.75
```

Casting it to the output as required in the question

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(percentage, player + opponent_name ~ game , value.var = "V1")
```

Result:

```
        player      opponent_name    1   2  3
1 Torri_Hunter     Detroit Tigers 0.75  NA NA
2 Torri_Hunter Pittsburgh Pirates 0.25 0.5  0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about writing two functions to help you? Assume that your dataframe is call df.

```
perc_res <- function(opponent, game="1" player="Torri_Hunter", result="home run"){
  return(
   dim(df[df$player==player & df$opponent==opponent & df$result==result & df$game==game,])[1]/
      dim(df[df$player==player & df$opponent==opponent & df$game==game,])[1]
 )
}
```

You can then make an output dataframe that looks like

```
out.df <- data.frame(Opponent=levels(factor(df$opponent)), Player="Torri_Hunter")
out.df$game1s <- lapply(out.df$Opponent, perc_res, game=1)
```

etc.
If you later want to have more players, you can use `mapply`.

ps: Haven't actually run the code so there might still be some general bugs. But I think this should at least get you started!